# Incorrect badge logo in achievements

Tags: bug, badges

The badge logo is incorrect in different sites. I found out that I had received the "Civic Duty" badge on Meta SO while I was browsing ELL, and to my surprise the badge logo was ELL style, not SO style (as seen in the first picture below).

[image: ell]

On SO, the logo is displayed correctly

[image: stackoverflow]

And on puzzling, the badge is a puzzle.

[image: puzzling]

I think that the badge logo should use the style of the logo on the site which it originated from, and now it just seems strange to me.